# Stripe - Refund Checkout Session

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I’m trying to implement a method for my connected account owners to be able to refund charges collected via a Stripe Checkout Session.

In order to do so, I want to use the following code:

```
const refund = await stripe.refunds.create({
                payment_intent: pi_id,
 });
```

In order to obtain the `payment_intent_id`, I am listening to the `checkout.session.completed` webhook, and accessing `data.object.payment_intent`.

When I attempt to create a refund using this payment intent id, I get the `No such paymentintent` error from Stripe. I noticed in my Stripe test account that there is a charge ID associated with the payment, so maybe I should be using that - but I’m not sure how to retrieve that programmatically from the checkout session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making the API call correctly.

“No such...” errors with Stripe are usually caused by either a mismatch in API keys (e.g. using a mixture of your test plus live keys) or by trying to access objects that exist on a different account (e.g. trying to perform an operation from your platform account on an object that was created on a connected account).